# Getting error of not a single group function in aggregated function

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE test1 (
    e_id       NUMBER(1),
    e_ques_id  NUMBER(10)
);

INSERT INTO test1 VALUES(1,3);
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES(1,4);

CREATE TABLE test_ref (
    code     NUMBER(1),
    c_value  VARCHAR2(20)
);

INSERT INTO test_ref VALUES(3,'May');
INSERT INTO test_ref VALUES(4,2022);

COMMIT;

Tool Used: SQL Developer(18c)
```

There are two tables `test1` and `test_ref` and I want to fetch the value from the `test_ref` table in order to bring month and year column value.

Expected Output:

```
+------+------------+
| e_id | month_year |
+------+------------+
|    1 | May 2022   |
+------+------------+
```

My attempt:

```
SELECT t.e_id,
LISTAGG(c_value,' ')month_year
FROM test1 t
JOIN test_ref tr ON(t.e_ques_id = tr.code)
WHERE t.e_ques_id IN(3,4)
GROUP BY t.e_id;
```

This is giving me the exact result that I am looking for but I need to add this logic in the existing view for which I need to use aggregated or case expression to bring the result. Hence I tried using `CASE` and `MAX` but it is giving me an error of not a single group function

My attempt (resulting in an error):

```
SELECT t.e_id,
MAX(CASE
WHEN t.e_ques_id IN(3,4) THEN LISTAGG(c_value,' ')
END )month_year
FROM test1 t
JOIN test_ref tr ON(t.e_ques_id = tr.code)
GROUP BY t.e_id;
```

Comment: Expressions in the `select` list, `having` and `order by` are calculated after the grouping is performed. So the context of such calculations is the list of expressions in the `group by`. **Everything** that is not in the `group by` or is not a function of `group by` expressions should be wrapped by an aggregate function. In your case it is `t.e_ques_id`, which should be moved into the `listagg` to perform conditional aggregation or added to the `group by` depending on the requirement

Comment: Another issue is a nested `max( listagg(....))`. Oracle allows two levels of aggregate functions, when the innermost is calculated on the `group by` expressions and the outermost is calculated on the result of them. As long as there's no the second `group by` clause, the result is a single group and can not have non aggregated expressions in the `select` list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can use Max() OVER() though I don't understand what you want to do, but maybe this can help...

```
WITH 
    test1 AS
        (
            SELECT 1 "E_ID", 3 "E_QUES_ID" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 1 "E_ID", 4 "E_QUES_ID" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 1 "E_ID", 5 "E_QUES_ID" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 1 "E_ID", 6 "E_QUES_ID" FROM DUAL 
        ),
    test_ref AS
        (
            SELECT 3 "CODE", 'May' "C_VALUE" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 4 "CODE", '2022' "C_VALUE" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 5 "CODE", 'Jun' "C_VALUE" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 6 "CODE", '2022' "C_VALUE" FROM DUAL 
        )
SELECT 
    E_ID,
    Max(LISTAGG(MY, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY E_ID, E_QUES_ID)) OVER() "MONTH_YEAR"
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            t.E_ID,
            t.E_QUES_ID,
            CASE WHEN t.E_QUES_ID IN(3, 4) THEN tr.C_VALUE END "MY"
        FROM
            test1 t
        INNER JOIN 
            test_ref tr ON(t.E_QUES_ID = tr.CODE)
        ORDER BY 
            t.E_ID,
            t.E_QUES_ID
    )
GROUP BY
    E_ID
```

Comment: Inner query transforms data with CASE expression preparing dataset for the main query. Now you can select the data from the question with max function and listagg without putting e_ques_id in the where clause. Inner query transformation could be done differently if needed. In my opinion problem with your errored code was in using e_ques_id which was not aggregated nor grouped by. Inner query is here just to avoid that and let you build your on logic further. Regards...

Answer (score 1):

To me, it is kind of difficult to guess *why* existing view requires  aggregate function or `case` expression.

Anyway: if you use `max` in its analytic form, skip `case` expression and - instead - move `e_ques_id` condition into the `where` clause (as you already did in query that *works*), you'd get this:

```
SQL>   SELECT t.e_id,
  2           MAX (LISTAGG (c_value, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY code))
  3              OVER (ORDER BY NULL) month_year
  4      FROM test1 t JOIN test_ref tr ON t.e_ques_id = tr.code
  5     WHERE t.e_ques_id IN (3, 4)
  6  GROUP BY t.e_id;

      E_ID MONTH_YEAR
---------- ---------------
         1 May 2022

SQL>
```

I have no idea whether this would (or would not) work in that view, but - you may try it.

Comment: I don't want to use ques_id in WHERE clause since this  table has other conditions as well in my existing view. Can we have any alternative wherein I can handle this scenario without giving ques_id in WHERE clause?

Comment: I wouldn't know. As I said, I can't imagine what you're actually doing and why. What result do you want if E_QUES_ID isn't IN (3, 4)? Additional sample data and (simplified) view script along with desired result might make things much more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation inside `LISTAGG`:

```sql
SELECT t.e_id,
       LISTAGG(CASE WHEN t.e_ques_id IN (3,4) THEN c_value END, ' ')
         WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY t.e_ques_id) AS month_year
FROM   test1 t
       JOIN test_ref tr ON(t.e_ques_id = tr.code)
GROUP BY t.e_id;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test1 (e_id, e_ques_id) AS
SELECT 1, LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5;

CREATE TABLE test_ref (code, c_value) AS
SELECT 1, 'Not this'        FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'May'             FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, '2022'            FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'Not this either' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | E_ID | MONTH_YEAR |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | May 2022 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=46186d0c5a50b86d3c32e64b327cc511)*